# Jboss Container specific restart

Tags: deployment, jboss, containers

We have a jboss server with multiple containers in it. Container1 deploying war1 and container2 deploying war2.

We use the command 
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh -S -s

Does this command restarts all the containers; or there is a ip-port config to trigger restart/shutdown for specific containers?

Is there even an option to restart individual/all containters? It would be great to see some documentation as to how they are managed from deployment perspective.

Comment: "container" isn't a term that JBoss uses... what are you referring to?

Comment: would it be context? Basically different folders under JBOSS_HOME/server/ is what I am calling as containers. 

For example my folder structure as mentioned above would be
JBOSS_HOMe/server/container1/deploy/war1.war
JBOSS_HOMe/server/container2/deploy/war2.war

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directories under `JBOSS_HOME/server` are called "configurations", and represent the configuration of a single instance of the JBoss server. When you start JBoss instance using `run.sh -c serverX` (or whatever your startup script looks like), the `-c serverX` refers to the configuration in `server/serverX`, and a JBoss will be started using `server/serverX` as its configuration.

When you shutdown a JBoss instance, the shutdown script doesn't refer to one of the configurations, it actually opens a network connection to the running server and tells it to shut down. So if only one server is running, that's the one that will be shutdown. If multiple servers are running at the same time, they must, by necessity, be running on different IP addresses or ports, and so the shutdown script must know which address/port to use to talk to that server.

JBoss provides no means to start/stop multiple servers at once - each one is a separate OS proces that you need to manage yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To shutdown a server using `shutdown.sh` you need to know where the server's JNDI-service is running/listening. The JNDI-service URL is specified with the `-s` or `--server` option:

```
# ./shutdown.sh -S --server jnp://<hostname>:<jndi-service-port>
```

If you don't use `-s` the shutdown script will (try to) shutdown the server with JNDI listening/running on `localhost:1099`.